# ReSharper "Possible NullReferenceException" wrong with FileInfo?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

I just started using ReSharper and I'm trying to identify why it thinks this code is wrong.

```
var file = new FileInfo("foobar");
return file.Directory.FullName;
```

It highlights `file.Directory` as a "Possible System.NullReferenceException". I'm not sure how this is possible because the file object can never be null and I can't figure out how the `DirectoryInfo` object returned from the `FileInfo` object could ever be null.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `Directory` property can indeed be `null`.  The implementation of the property is roughly

```
public DirectoryInfo Directory {
    get {
        string directoryName = this.DirectoryName;
        if (directoryName == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new DirectoryInfo(directoryName);
    }
}
```

It can definitely return `null`.  Here is a concrete example

```
var x = new FileInfo(@"c:\");
if (x.Directory == null) {
  Console.WriteLine("Directory is null");  // Will print
}
```

Comment: Additionally: one could use [`file.DirectoryName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) which will return "the directory's full path", and should also work for `"c:\"`.